# Spacing on text macros

Tags: spacing

With the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% --- PACKAGES --- 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem, breqn}

% --- COMMANDS --- 
\newcommand{\problems}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]}
\newcommand{\close}{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\spn}{\operatorname{span}}

\begin{document}

\problems

% Problem 1
\item ($5$ points) Suppose that $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}, T = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m\}$ are two finite subsets of $V$ such that $S$ is linearly independent and $T$ is linearly independent. If $\spn(S) \cap \spn(T) = \{0\}$, prove that $S \cup T$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$.

\close

\end{document}
```

I get the following result 
[image: actual result]

At the end of the second line, I would like a space after the intersection symbol like this: 
[image: desired result]

Oddly, this seems to work if I make minor, seemingly unrelated changes such as removing the `($5$ points)`.

EDIT 1: Added a minimum working example. 
EDIT 2: Changed to `\operatorname` from `\text` (no change in result).

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a fully compilable Minimum Working Example, rather than just a code snippet, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Welcome. // Please extend your code, so it starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, compiles when copied AND shows your problem. That will be much easier for everybody involved. Thank you

Comment: As MS-SPO has said, a minimum working example (MWE) will help a lot. Actually, in standard `article` with `amsmath` or `mathtools` loaded, I am getting your desired result. // I will also suggest using `\newcommand{\spn}{\operatorname{span}}` instead of `\text`.

Comment: Sorry about that! Added a working example and clarified my issue.

Comment: @arz: You could consider `\,{\cap}\,`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that plain TeX (and LaTeX too) sets

```
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
```

and `\medmuskip` is inserted by TeX around binary operators (like `\cap`). It means that if a line in a paragraph is very tight (as in your example) then the result from `\medmuskip` can be `4mu minus 4mu`, so it can be zero.

You can try to re-set `\medmuskip` primitive register if you disagree with such a result.

Answer (score 2):

You're being unlucky, because if I “freeze” the spacing, the paragraphs is still well typeset. How do I get the “freezing”? By surrounding the expression with braces.

Note that math such as

```
Suppose that $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}, T = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m\}$ are
```

should be *two* formulas

```
Suppose that $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$, $T = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m\}$ are
```

You can check the space after the outer comma in the two versions to see why I recommend this; besides, this helps in making paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% --- PACKAGES ---
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem, breqn}

% --- COMMANDS ---
\newcommand{\problems}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]}
\newcommand{\close}{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\spn}{\operatorname{span}}

\begin{document}

\problems

% Problem 1
\item ($5$ points) Suppose that $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$,
  $T = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m\}$ are two finite subsets of $V$
  such that $S$ is linearly independent and $T$ is linearly independent.
  If ${\spn(S) \cap \spn(T)} = \{0\}$, prove that $S \cup T$ is a linearly
  independent subset of $V$.

\close

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you might decide for changing `\medmuskip` on a global basis.

With

```
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 1mu
```

and no additional braces you'd get

[image]